# How can i pass the selected data objects to another page

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

[image: When i click the add button]

HEllo, how can i pass the selected object data when I want to select more than one and pass it into another page and put it as a list. How can i achieve this ? [image: The product will be the parameter that will be passed into another page]
But how can i pass the parameter when i select more than one object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your products to an array first

```
productList = [] as any[];

productList.push(product);

this.navCtrl.push(OrderPage,{ productList: productList});
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you can pass different ways to pass data to other pages

> > by Query Parameters(if parameters are not secret);

from ts file

```
this.router.navigate(
   ['/path'], 
   { queryParams: { key1: valu1, key2: value2, key3: value3 } 
});
```

from html file

```
<a [routerLink]="['/path']"
   [queryParams]="{ key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3 }">
  Something    </a>
```

path will be like http://localhost:4200/path?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3

You can get by

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });
}
```

> > by Linking to Routes with Parameters

```
this.router.navigate(['/path', {key1: value1, key2: value2}]);
```

check the parameters by

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });
}
```